# Android app for Blackberry - 'result::failure -2' Packaging APK to BAR

Tags: android, android-studio, blackberry, apk

I am trying to install my android app built on Android Studio onto my Blackberry 10 device. I have installed the plugin and followed all the instructions on the Blackberry Developer website to ensure a proper installation.

When trying to to package my signed APK to BAR, I receive the following error message:

```
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 1184355
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 1184355 bytes
Info: Progress 50%...
Info: Progress 100%...
actual_dname::com.example.example.gYABgAoVA.LaGD2sxj1qHQWnizw
actual_id::gYABgAoVA-LaGD2sxj1qHQWnizw
actual_version::1.0.1.0
result::failure -2
com.qnx.bbt.deploy.Deploy$DeployException: result::failure -2
```

I do not understand this error message, and have no idea how to overcome it. I have checked on the Blackberry Developer website, yet nothing includes my `result::failure -2` anyone have the same problem or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Failure -2 means that the app does not the support the version of Android that you are running.

Blackberry 10 at the time of writing runs Android 4.3 Jelly Bean. More and more apps these days have Android 4.4 or higher as their minimum OS requirement.

Unfortunately Blackberry have said that they plan to make their Android 4.3 runtime more secure, instead of updating it. So don't expect the app you tried to work any time soon :/